# Android Studio: save and load an ArrayList using SharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, save, load, sharedpreferences

Just like the question asks. I had some trouble saving and loading to shared preferences with an app I'm making since I am using ArrayLists as well as fragments.

I've posted the answer below in the hopes that it helps out any of you who might have been as tripped up as I was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick template to save a list to sharedpreferences in whatever app you're making (this, as well as loadList are outside of your OnCreate method:

```
private void saveList(ArrayList<YourObject> yourList, String yourKey) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(yourList);

    prefsEditor.putString(yourKey, json);

    prefsEditor.apply();
}
```

Where it says `...(this.getApplicationContext());`, for Fragments, you would use `...(getActivity());`

Also, be sure to use `.apply();` and not `.commit();` at the end, as apply runs in the background.
This save method also works with any object, not just lists. All you have to do is in place of `...saveList(ArrayList<YourObjectItems> yourList,...`, just enter a different object, such as `...saveList(String yourString,...`

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

Here's the template for the loadList method:

```
private ArrayList<YourObject> loadList(String yourKey) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(yourKey, null);

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObject>>() {}.getType();

    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

If you want to load something other than a list, let's say a String value, on the second to last line you'd put: `Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType();`

IMPORTANT!!!
In order to use `Gson()`, you have to put

`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`

under "dependencies" in Gradle Scripts --> `build.gradle (Module: app)`.

I believe this should cover everything. Comment on any edits I should make. Hope this helps out some people. Also, FYI, I'm using this on an app I'm building on an API 24 build with Android 7.0. I don't know if this works for older versions, but new versions should be able to handle it.